# Making equal number of records

Tags: awk

I have a file with few single records and few multiple records based on field one. There will be maximum of 5 such records. How can I make each record into 5 records depending on field one.

```
623526 20010202
623526 20010309
785426 20011008
785426 20010905
785426 20010709
895623 20010905
935545 20020101
935545 20020102
935545 20020103
935545 20020104
935545 20020105
```

The output

```
623526 20010202
623526 20010309
623526
623526
623526
785426 20011008
785426 20010905
785426 20010709
785426
785426
895623 20010905
895623
895623
895623
895623
935545 20020101
935545 20020102
935545 20020103
935545 20020104
935545 20020105
```

I have tried but this could add only one record of each different value of field one.

```
awk '{ar[$1]++
print $0
}
END {
for (num in ar)
{if (ar[num]<=4)
print num
}
}' input | sort
```

Comment: Is your input sorted according field 1? And what if you already have 5 or more records with the same field 1? And, finally, please show what you tried up to now and explain why the result is wrong.

Comment: The close reason here is slightly misleading. There are not really multiple questions here. We used to have a "too broad" reason which included "lacks effort or demonstration of any research" but the correct close reason now would really be "needs details or clarity". Anyway, please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask;](/help/how-to-ask) perhaps you can still edit this into a form which is acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oops! Yes they are in sorting order.
The following could add only one extra record.
awk '{ar[$1]++
print $0
}
END {
for (num in ar)
{if (ar[num]<=4)
print num
}
}' input | sort

Comment: @Mac Please edit your question and make clear that the input is sorted according field 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution with `awk` and `sort` would *almost* work with a `for` loop instead of a single `print num`:

```
for(i=ar[num];i<5;i++) print num
```

*Almost* only because sort prints the added lines first, while in your expected output they appear after the original lines.

You could also insert the missing records on the fly, each time field 1 changes. This would avoid a call to `sort`, it would be less memory hungry and would produce exactly what you want:

```
awk 'BEGIN {n=5}
     $1!=p || NR==1 {for(;n<5;n++) print p; p=$1; n=0}
     {print; n+=1}
     END {for(;n<5;n++) print p}' foo.txt
```

We use variable `p` to store field 1 values and `n` to count the consecutive records with same field 1 value. `n` is initialized to 5 in the `BEGIN` block before reading the first record to start in a clean state.

The second block is executed only if the first field changed or if it is the first record of the file. If `n<5` we print the `n-5` missing records. Then we update `p` and `n`.

The third block prints the current record and increments `n`.

The `END` block is executed after the last record of the file has been processed. It prints the `n-5` last missing records, if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have got it with if else...but yours is a crypto.